# I would like to know the different solutions, I am attaching my solution thanks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0

They believe that this solution is fine, I have not been programming for a long time, I have been about 1 month, my question is what other ways I opened to solve the following problem, I attach my solution.

```
Sample Input 1 2 3 4 5 

Sample Output 10 14
```

The numbers are 1,2,3,4, and 5.

> Calculate the following sums using four of the five integers: Sum everything except 1,the sum is 2+3+4+5=14. Sum everything except 2,the sum is 1+3+4+5=13. Sum everything except 3,the sum is 1+2+4+5=12. Sum everything except 4,the sum is 1+2+3+5=11. Sum everything except 5,the sum is 1+2+3+4=10.

---

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

miniMaxSum(arr);
}



static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr)
{
List<int> arr2 = new List<int>();
int sum = 0,mn,mx;
int sum2 = 0;
int sum3 = 0;
int sum4 = 0;
int sum5 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
if(i != 0)
{
sum = sum + arr[i];

}
if (i != 1)
{
sum2 = sum2 + arr[i];

}
if (i!= 2)
{
sum3 = sum3 + arr[i];
}
if (i != 3)
{
sum4 = sum4 + arr[i];
 
}
if (i != 4)
{
sum5 = sum5 + arr[i];
}

}
arr2.Add(sum);
arr2.Add(sum2);
arr2.Add(sum3);
arr2.Add(sum4);
arr2.Add(sum5);
mx = arr2[0];
mn = arr2[0];
for (int j = 0; j < arr2.Count; j++)
{
if (arr2[j] > mx)
{
mx = arr2[j];
}
if(arr2[j] < mn)
{
mn = arr2[j];
}

}
Console.Write(mn + " ");
Console.Write(mx);
         

}
```

Comment: Also the description doesn't match the output

Comment: evidently the question should be 'and output the minimum and maximum values obtained'

Comment: The simplest approach, given a list of `n` numbers, is to sum them *all*, duplicate the sum `n` times, then *subtract* the number that you want to "sum without".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description doesn't match the output. However, assuming the description is correct

> Calculate the following sums using four of the five integers:
>
> - Sum everything except 1, the sum is `2+3+4+5=14`.
> - Sum everything except 2,the sum is `1+3+4+5=13`.
> - Sum everything except 3,the sum is `1+2+4+5=12`.
> - Sum everything except 4,the sum is `1+2+3+5=11`.
> - Sum everything except 5,the sum is `1+2+3+4=10`.

You can do the following

---

You can just use 2 loops

```
var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for (var i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0);i++)
{
   var sum = 0;
   for (var j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(0); j++)
      if (i != j) 
         sum += arr[j];
   Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

**Output**

```
14
13
12
11
10
```

---

Or if you like *Linq Chain Methods*

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0);i++)
{
   var sum = arr.Where((x, j) => i != j ).Sum();
   Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

---

Or you if hate for loops *with a passion*

```
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, arr.GetLength(0))
   .Select(i => arr
      .Where((x, j) => i != j)
      .Sum());

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results));
```

---

Or if *Extension Methods* are your thing

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FunkyIterator<T>(this T[] source)
   => Enumerable.Range(0, source.GetLength(0))
        .Select(i => source.Where((x, j) => i != j));

...

foreach (var iterations in arr.FunkyIterator())
   Console.WriteLine(iterations.Sum());
```

Answer (score 1):

For this one you can take a look at Statistics' **Combination** Formula, which gets all the possible **r** elements out of **n** elements, **C(n, r)**.

This is the method to get all the possible combinations:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
{
    return k == 0 ? new[] { new T[0] } :
          elements.SelectMany((e, i) => elements.Skip(i + 1)
               .Combinations(k - 1)
               .Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
```

First I'm gonna try using it in your case. You have the array like so.

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Then you want to sum every `4` numbers in your array, like 1,2,3,4 ; 1,2,4,5 ; 1,2,3,5 ; ... etc. So you can use the method above with a Linq method called `Sum()`.

```
foreach(IEnumerable<int> result in arr.Combinations(4))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Sum());
}
```

Also, if you want to sum every `3` element instead, like 1,2,3 ; 3,4,5 ; 1,2,5 ; ... etc, you only need to change the parameter `k` in the method Combinations:

```
foreach(IEnumerable<int> result in arr.Combinations(3))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Sum());
}
```

Last but not least, the above method that I provided is an extension methods, so be sure to put it in a `static` class, and don't forget to add a reference to `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a slightly different approach from the other two answers that are currently posted. I'm going to slowly improve your solution one step at a time. I'm going to avoid LINQ; don't get me wrong LINQ is cool and you should definitely learn it, but it's useful to know what is going on inside. For more about LINQ see @General's answer above.

The first thing I would notice is that your solution only works when there are five elements in the array. The first version I am going to show you is one that removes this limitation.

But before I do that I want to write two helper functions that will come in handy: `Max` and `Min`. These functions take an array and return the maximum element and minimum element respectively.

```cs
    static int Min(int[] arr)
    {
        int min = int.MaxValue;
        foreach (var val in arr)
        {
            min = Math.Min(min, val);
        }
        return min;
    }
    
    static int Max(int[] arr)
    {
        int max = int.MinValue;
        foreach (var val in arr)
        {
            max = Math.Max(max, val);
        }
        return max;
    }
```

With these in hand we can write a version of your function that will handle an array of any size.

```cs
    /// Adds capability to work with arrays longer the 5 elements.
    static void MinMaxSum1(int[] arr)
    {
        // This array will hold the sums obtained if
        // the corresponding element in the input
        // array was left out of the sum.
        // So sums[0] is the sum if the zeroth element
        // is left out.
        int[] sums = new int[arr.Length];
        // skip is the index of the element we'll leave out
        // of the sum
        for (int skip = 0; skip < arr.Length; skip++)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int current = 0; current < arr.Length; current++)
            {
                if (current != skip)
                {
                    sum += arr[current];
                }
            }
            sums[skip] = sum;
            Console.WriteLine($"MinMaxSum1: arr[{skip}] = {arr[skip]} sums[{skip}] = {sum}");
        }
        int min = Min(sums);
        int max = Max(sums);
        Console.WriteLine($"MinMaxSum1: min={min} max={max}");
        Console.WriteLine("================================");  
    }
```

It's worthwhile to take a moment and consider how many operations this will do if the array has *n* elements. The inner loop will do *n-1* additions and the outer loop will cause this to run *n* times, so roughly *n<sup>2</sup>* additions, the `Min` and `Max` methods perform *n* comparisons each. So roughly *n<sup>2</sup> + 2n* operations.

Can we do better?

Well, yes, we can. If you look at the output you may realize that `arr[i] + sum[i] == 15`. This makes sense there are two ways to get the answer:

- add the elements skipping the one you want to leave out
- add all the elements and subtract the one you want to leave out.
  Notice the sum of all the elements is not going to change!

So if we have a helper function `Sum` that sums all the elements in the array we can write:

```cs
    static void MinMaxSum2(int[] arr)
    {
        int sum = Sum(arr);
        int[] sums = new int[arr.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sums.Length; ++i)
        {
            sums[i] = sum - arr[i];
            Console.WriteLine($"MinMaxSum2: arr[{i}] = {arr[i]} sums[{i}] = {sums[i]}");
        }
        int min = Min(sums);
        int max = Max(sums);
        Console.WriteLine($"MinMaxSum2: min={min} max={max}");
        Console.WriteLine("================================");          
    }
```

This goes through the array once to compute the `sum` performing *n* additions, another time to compute the `sums` array performing *n* subtractions and the `Min` and `Max` routines perform *n* comparisons each, so about *4n* operations in total.

Can we do better?

Again yes, but this time we need to look at part of your solution that was not mentioned in the question text. It looks like you only need the min and max partial sums. From the implementation above I hope you can see that the min will occur for `sum - Max(arr)` and the max will occur for `sum - Min(arr)`.

This leads to this implementation:

```cs
    static void MinMaxSum3(int[] arr)
    {
        int min = Min(arr);
        int max = Max(arr);
        int sum = Sum(arr);
        Console.WriteLine($"MinMaxSum3: min sum = {sum - max}");
        Console.WriteLine($"MinMaxSum3: max sum = {sum - min}");
        Console.WriteLine("================================");
    }
```

You can find all these versions, along with the implementation of `Sum` and one bonus implementation on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nnQvWI)

Comment: Thanks , I need to practice a lot more, some book or page that you recommend to continue learning and be able to live from this

Comment: I don't have a good book recommendation for C#, but for algorithms in general you could take a look at [MIT 6.006 - Introduction to Algorithms](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/) the lectures are free on YouTube. If it's too hard to follow for you now, bookmark it and come back to it later!

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach?

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var total = arr.Sum();
List<int> sums = new List<int>();
foreach(int i in arr) {
  sums.Add(total - i);
}
var min = sums.Min();
var max = sums.Max();

Console.WriteLine("min = " + min);
Console.WriteLine("max = " + max);
```

Or, if you don't want to use any LINQ:

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

int total = 0;    
foreach(int i in arr) {
  total += i;
}
int min = 0, max = 0;
for(int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++) {
  int sum = total - arr[i];
  if (i == 0) {
    min = sum;
    max = sum;
  }
  else {
    if (sum < min) {
      min = sum;
    }
    if (sum > max) {
      max = sum;
    }
  }
}

Console.WriteLine("min = " + min);
Console.WriteLine("max = " + max);
```